# How to disable Rocket Launcher on Silverstripe CMS Javascript?

Tags: javascript, silverstripe, cloudflare

A client of ours has a Silverstripe website that they're hosting with a company that applies the Cloudflare CDN to their hosting plan.

We can't access the Cloudflare settings but want to alter one of the settings "Rocket Launcher" so it doesn't touch the Silverstripe CMS Javascript files (lib.js, leftandmain.js).

[It is possible to make Rocket Launcher ignore a script](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169436-How-can-I-have-Rocket-Loader-ignore-my-script-s-in-Automatic-Mode-):

`<script data-cfasync="false" src="/javascript.js"></script>`

However the CMS javascript is dynamically loaded by core Silverstripe code:

`Requirements::combine_files('leftandmain.js', $leftAndMainIncludes);`

Is it possible to add the `data-cfasync="false"` variable to the script tag by extending the core code?

I want the output to read:

`<script type="text/javascript" data-cfasync="false" src="/assets/_combinedfiles/leftandmain.js?m=1486678668"></script>`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think so. The script tags that get generated are hard coded into `Requirements::includeInHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look to be an easy place in Requirements_Backend. Could do it using a RequestFilter. Use a regex or simple replace to modify the response body.

Comment: [Do not parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2812842)!

Comment: @RobbieAverill a simple search/replace for some scripts / urls should be enough.